# Modelbinding List Custom Models Sent by JSON Does Not Deserialze Properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, model-binding

I have recreated an example app to reflect what I am facing. That [can be grabbed here](https://app.box.com/s/y0z2li3ppiwz4p7ycnoq) (if it helps troubleshoot).

I have the following model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int[] Members { get; set; }
}
```

I want to send a list of them to my controller, so I have an Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<MyModel> myModel)
{
    return View();
}
```

The Javascript to build and send the payload is as follows:

```
$(function () {

    $('#submitButton').on('click', function () {

        var memberSelectors = $([]);

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            var item = {
                id: 'idval-' + i,
                vals: [5, 2, 8]
            };

            memberSelectors.push(item);
        }

        var models = [];

        memberSelectors.each(function (idx, val) {
            var myModel = {
                'myModel.Id': val['id'].toString(),
                'myModel.Members': val.vals
            };
            models.push(myModel);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(models)
        });

    });

})
```

If anyone can suggest why the json payload is not being successfully changes to a list of MyModel objects in the Action parameter, I would be much obliged.

Just to confirm, the json payload is in the exact form that I want it in. i.e.

```
[{
    "myModel.Id": "idval-0",
    "myModel.Members": [5,
    2,
    8]
},
{
    "myModel.Id": "idval-1",
    "myModel.Members": [5,
    2,
    8]
},
{
    "myModel.Id": "idval-2",
    "myModel.Members": [5,
    2,
    8]
},
{
    "myModel.Id": "idval-3",
    "myModel.Members": [5,
    2,
    8]
}]
```

Thanks!

**Edit:** json payload is now a proper Javascript array.
This is what is being sent to the server:

```
[{"myModel.Id":"idval-0","myModel.Members":[5,2,8]},{"myModel.Id":"idval-1","myModel.Members":[5,2,8]},{"myModel.Id":"idval-2","myModel.Members":[5,2,8]},{"myModel.Id":"idval-3","myModel.Members":[5,2,8]}]
```

Comment: That JSON structure is not what your ActionResult is setup to handle.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you're being down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON structure does not accurately represent what you're trying to bind to.  In JSON terms you're trying to bind to an array of `MyModel`'s.

Your structure should look something like this:

```
var models = [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Members": [1,2,3]
    }
]
```

Comment: I changed the Javascript to send a proper array. Now, a C# object is passed into the Action method, but each member of the array contains null values i.e. Id and Members of each object is null.

Comment: Can you post what you're actually sending to the server?

Comment: I have added at the foot of the post exactly what is being sent to the server. Did you want http headers as well? Or just the json.

Comment: I got this working. I changed the properties to not include the "myModel." prefix. Which, I just noticed, is what your answer suggests. Thanks!